# Django querying

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have writing a code where I need the value of the total frequency of words.
I need to multiply this value to another value, but I can't do that because my code is returning a query set ({frequency_sum: 15}). All I need is the 15, so I can multiply with other variables, please how do I write the code so when I request for Dictionary. Objects.aggregate (Sum(frequency)), I could get just the 15 and nothing else

Comment: Please add the code of the files that you are mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dictionary, so you can retrieve the value by subscripting, like:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

the_value = Model.objects.aggregate(Sum('frequency'))['frequency__sum']
```

Or you can give your aggregate a name you define yourself, like:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

the_value = Model.objects.aggregate(sum_fq=Sum('frequency'))['sum_fq']
```